# Unable to locate Secure Agent under Develop in Salesforce

Tags: salesforce

I tried logging a case asking salesforce about this but was rejected and directed here. Can anyone here shine a light on why I don't get this option in my Setup menu?

I am attempting to follow the guidelines in this help article: https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=external_secure_agent.htm

and I am unable to comply with the step that reads:

> Setup **-->**  Develop **-->** Secure Agents

This option does not appear in my org's setup menu. Is there anything I need to activate or configure before that can happen?

Comment: What is the type of salesforce Org which you're using?

Comment: I do not see any other reason except absence a “Customize Application” right in your profile. I checked this point on my developer and enterprise orgs. Check your profile.

Comment: I am using a Sandbox of Enterprise Edition. Is it not available in sandbox